# How switch off music using jQuery

Tags: jquery, soundcloud

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var widget = SC.Widget(document.getElementById('soundcloud_widget'));

    widget.bind(SC.Widget.Events.READY, function() {
        console.log('Ready...');
    });

    $('#soundcloudbutton').click(function() {
        $('#soundcloudbutton').toggleClass('soundcloudpause');
        $('#soundcloudbutton').toggleClass('soundcloudplay');
        widget.toggle();
    });

    $('.mute-the-music').click(function() {
        $('#soundcloudbutton').toggleClass('soundcloudplay');
        widget.false();
    });
});
```

How do you make the `widget.false` line trigger the soundcloud player to stop playing? I can't work out the the singular version of the toggle function.

Cheers,
Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play and mute the sound, you have `.play()` and `.pause()`, which is the *on / off* setting for `.toggle()`.

You may also want to replace `.toggleClass()` with `.removeClass()` since you want it to stop in this case, not toggle.

```
$('.mute-the-music').click(function() {
    $('#soundcloudbutton').removeClass('soundcloudplay');
    widget.pause();
});
```